# Set icon color in toggle button depending on toggle button state

Tags: xaml, winui-3

I got a problem with my `ToggleButton` and its content.
I hope this information is sufficient, let me know if you need anything else!

### Problem

I have a `ToggleButton` that contains a `FontIcon` and a `TextBlock` in a `Grid`:

```
<ToggleButton Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
    <Grid>
         <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
             <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
             <ColumnDefinition Width="3*"/>
         </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

         <FontIcon Grid.Column="0"
                   FontSize="20"
                   Glyph="{StaticResource mdi_handyman}"
                   FontFamily="{StaticResource MaterialDesignIconsOutlined}"/>
         <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Margin="10,0,0,0" Text="{x:Bind p:Resources.Dashboard_Maintenance}"/>
     </Grid>
</ToggleButton>
```

The text in the `ToggleButton` should always be white. That's why I set following resources for the `ToggleButton`:

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ToggleButtonForeground" Color="{ThemeResource WhiteColor}"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ToggleButtonForegroundDisabled" Color="{ThemeResource WhiteColor}"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ToggleButtonForegroundPointerOver" Color="{ThemeResource WhiteColor}"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ToggleButtonForegroundChecked" Color="{ThemeResource RichBlackColor}"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ToggleButtonForegroundCheckedPointerOver" Color="{ThemeResource RichBlackColor}"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ToggleButtonForegroundPressed" Color="{ThemeResource WhiteColor}"/>

<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ToggleButtonBackground" Color="{ThemeResource RichBlackColor}"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ToggleButtonBackgroundDisabled" Color="{ThemeResource RichBlackColor}"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ToggleButtonBackgroundPointerOver" Color="{ThemeResource LightPrussianBlueColor}"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ToggleButtonBackgroundChecked" Color="{ThemeResource VividSkyBlueColor}"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ToggleButtonBackgroundCheckedDisabled" Color="{ThemeResource PaleVividSkyBlueColor}"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ToggleButtonBackgroundCheckedPointerOver" Color="{ThemeResource VividSkyBlueColor}"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ToggleButtonBackgroundPressed" Color="{ThemeResource LightPrussianBlueColor}"/>
```

Now there is the requirement to add the `FontIcon` in the `Grid` as well. But this `FontIcon` behaves the same as the text (obviously as the resources for the `ToggleButton` foreground are for the whole content).

However the `FontIcon` needs following behavior in the `ToggleButton`:

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ToggleButtonForeground" Color="{ThemeResource VividSkyBlue}"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ToggleButtonForegroundDisabled" Color="{ThemeResource VividSkyBlue}"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ToggleButtonForegroundPointerOver" Color="{ThemeResource VividSkyBlue}"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ToggleButtonForegroundChecked" Color="{ThemeResource RichBlackColor}"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ToggleButtonForegroundCheckedPointerOver" Color="{ThemeResource RichBlackColor}"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ToggleButtonForegroundPressed" Color="{ThemeResource WhiteColor}"/>
```

### My guess

I guess I could solve this with a converter for the `FontIcon` Foreground that binds to the selected state of the `ToggleButton` but this converter would also need the disabled state of the `ToggleButton` which makes this a bit more compley.
As I think I would be able to get this running I think this might be a bit hacky and not satisfying.

Does anyone have an idea how to solve this more elegant?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the **Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors.WinUI.Managed** NuGet package.

Here's the code but I changed the colors to check if this works.

```xml
<FontIcon
    x:Name="ThisFontIcon"
    Grid.Column="0"
    FontSize="20"
    Glyph="{StaticResource CheckBoxCheckedGlyph}">
    <interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="PointerEntered">
            <core:ChangePropertyAction
                PropertyName="Foreground"
                TargetObject="{Binding ElementName=ThisFontIcon}"
                Value="HotPink" />
        </core:EventTriggerBehavior>
        <core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="PointerExited">
            <core:ChangePropertyAction
                PropertyName="Foreground"
                TargetObject="{Binding ElementName=ThisFontIcon}"
                Value="{ThemeResource SystemAccentColor}" />
        </core:EventTriggerBehavior>

        <core:DataTriggerBehavior
            Binding="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=ThisToggleButton}"
            Value="True">
            <core:ChangePropertyAction
                PropertyName="Foreground"
                TargetObject="{Binding ElementName=ThisFontIcon}"
                Value="{ThemeResource SystemChromeBlackHighColor}" />
        </core:DataTriggerBehavior>
        <core:DataTriggerBehavior
            Binding="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=ThisToggleButton}"
            Value="False">
            <core:ChangePropertyAction
                PropertyName="Foreground"
                TargetObject="{Binding ElementName=ThisFontIcon}"
                Value="{ThemeResource SystemAccentColor}" />
        </core:DataTriggerBehavior>
    </interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
</FontIcon>
```

Comment: I tried it and it worked. Sadly I was not allowed to introduce the nuget package into our application. That's why I solved it with a converter at the end.
Will still mark it as the accepted solution as it worked for me! 
Thank you again :D